# How is the implicit cast from enum type to int possible?

Tags: c++, enums

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

using namespace std;

enum dayOfWeek : short { M = 10, TU, W, TH, F, SA, SU };

int main()
{
    dayOfWeek d = TU;
    int u = d; // HOW ???
    return 0;
}
```

Now could anybody explain to me how this happens? How did this implicit cast work?

Comment: It works because the language says so. And it was most likely inherited from C. However, those days are over with stronger enums. `enum class`

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. This question is about an implicit **conversion**.

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit cast there. You explicitly made (C++11 and above) the underlying type of your `enum` a `short`; which is implicitly convertible to `int` in your assignment.

However, whether you have an explicit underlying type, or not, the C++ standard explicitly states that the values of unscoped enums are implicitly convertible to integral types.

This is not the case with `enum class` which is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for `enum` the values are implicitly convertible to integral types

> Values of unscoped enumeration type are implicitly-convertible to integral types. If the underlying type is not fixed, the value is convertible to the first type from the following list able to hold their entire value range: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, or `unsigned long long`. If the underlying type is fixed, the values can be converted to their promoted underlying type.

If you want to disallow this implicit conversion you can use an `enum class`

```
enum class dayOfWeek : short { M = 10, TU, W, TH, F, SA, SU };

int main()
{
    dayOfWeek d = dayOfWeek::TU;
    int u = static_cast<int>(d);
    return 0;
}
```